# How to receive 2 notifications via NSNotificationCenter

Tags: objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I have three methods:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self updateViews];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveNotification:) name:@"itemQuantityChanged" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveNotification:) name:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item %@ deleted", itemUUID] object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void) receiveNotification: (NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"itemQuantityChanged"])
        [self updateViews];
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item %@ deleted", itemUUID]])
        NSLog(@"FAIL!");
}
```

The main idea is that for this class I need to receive 2 different notifications and in case of receiving them need to perform different actions. Is everything ok with the realization? I believe that it is possible to simplify this code. How to `removeObserver` correctly? I don't use ARC.

Comment: Seems fine though I usually subscribe in viewDidLoad and unsubscribe in dealloc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a different selector for each notification. That way, you don't need any logic in the method to determine which notification was sent.

Removing the observers as you are doing is fine.